# URL Rewriting in IIS 7

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, iis-7.5

I have the existing rule as xml that will rewrite or redirect any request to a specific url to its domain. It won't let any outbound request go out of the domain.

I want to add an EXCEPTION to only one url (say abc.com). How to add an exception to a particular request?

(please donot provide anything like global.asax because IIS is not working with ASP.NET application but with some other application).

current rule:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="topcontent">
           <match-url=".*">
                <action type="rewrite" url="mysite.com/{R:0}"/>
           </match-url>
       </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

If any inbound request comes it rewrites the url to mysite.com. I need to add an exception to say abc.com/...... How to do this?

Comment: Are you really rewriting request to other domains, i.e. using IIS as a reverse proxy (URL Rewrite with ARR), or do you want to redirect requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use below code:

```
<rule name="special" enabled="true">
  <match url=".*" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" >
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)?abc\.com$" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://mysite.com/{R:0}"/>
</rule>
```

a condition has been added to the rule, so if it does not come true, then the action will be executed (`negate="true"`)

it will check the `http://{HTTP_HOST}/url` and if it does not match **abc.com** or **www.abc.com** which is exception here, then it will go for the action.

also I think that you may use `Redirect` here instead of `Rewrite`

Comment: Consider my domain is abc.com and the outgoing domain is xyz.com. The current 'topcontent' rule will change the url and not allow to go to the external domain. Can you explain me what5 is this {R:0} and {C:0} and all used for ? And how <match url="">'s url's regular expression is built ? Thanks.

Comment: For {C:0} & {R:0} which are back-references, please follow [Using Back-references in Rewrite Rules](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-20-configuration-reference#Using_back-references_in_rewrite_rules).  
In _<match url=...>_, **.*** (where "." means any character and "*" means 0 or more repeats) will filter **any** URLs after last slash in the URI.  as a simple guide for Regular Expressions please follow [Simple RegEx Tutorial](http://www.icewarp.com/support/online_help/203030104.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Create another rule above the `topcontent` rule:

```
<rule name="special">
    <match-url="abc.com">
        <action type="rewrite" url="mysite.com/specialPage.htm"/>
    </match-url>
</rule>
```

Here is a similar question: [IIS URL rewrite exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9507653/iis-url-rewrite-exception)

Answer (score 0):

Go into IIS Manager > [your site] > Url Rewrite.

Add a new rule before this one that matches abc.com and check "Stop processing of subsequent rules".

Comment: can you please show me in xml? because I have no knowledge of regular expressions and url rewriting.